# OPENSSL_API_COMPAT expresses an impossible API compatibility level c++

Tags: c++, openssl, hmac, sha

#error:  "OPENSSL_API_COMPAT expresses an impossible API compatibility level" why when I import these 2 lines of code it gives me the error above?

```
#define OPENSSL_API_COMPAT 0x10101000L
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be happening because the value of `OPENSSL_API_COMPAT` doesn't match anything that's supported by the openssl header you're including.

Likely scenario in your case would be that the installed version of openssl on your system is 1.1.0 or below.

You can find more details about what is happening by peeking at the `openssl/macros.h` header, at the line that triggers the error. You'll be able to tell if it happened because the version number was too high, too low, or just invalid.